# How to select every category of a column in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have a dataframe something like this.
[image]

I want to calculate the variance and standard deviation of co2_emission for each food_category by grouping and aggregating. And it has to be in this format

```
print(food_consumption.____(____)['co2_emission'].agg([____]))
```

This is I have done so far

```
print(food_consumption. .....(....)['co2_emission'].agg([np.var(food_consumption['co2_emission'], ddof=1),np.sqrt(np.var(food_consumption['co2_emission'], ddof=1))]))
```

I have to select the each category of the column named food_category. how to do that?

Comment: If `agg` corresponds to "aggregating", what do you think "grouping" should correspond to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because pandas [`Series.var`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.var.html) and [`Series.std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.std.html) has default `ddof=1` pass them to `agg`:

```
print(food_consumption.groupby('food_category')['co2_emission'].agg(['var','std']))
```

Comment: I forgot the function groupby(). Thanks!!!